# How to install mobile application(Android/iOS) in emulators directly by accessing path from different network location using appium?

Tags: selenium, appium

I'm launching my android & ios emulators in windows & mac machine respectively,

My application is generated by CI system in a network location (path: \xxx.yyy.com\\Mobile\android and \xxx.yyy.com\\Mobile\ios)

If try to install the mobile app in emulators by directly accessing the path(path:\xxx.yyy.com\\Mobile\android), getting below error. How to handle this situation?

Error in console :

Exception encountered in getDriver Method: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat '\xxx.yyy.com\\Mobile\android\android_application.apk' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 23.25 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'MOBILETESTTR01', ip: '10.7.0.86', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver

Environment:

Appium version that exhibits the issue: 1.8.0
Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: Windows 10
Real device or emulator/simulator:simulator
Selenium server: 2.53.1
java-client: 4.0.0

is there any way to install the mobile app by directly accessing the path using appium ? Please suggest .

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can checkin apk file as a part of you project in git and then use following capability,appium will auto install the apk.

```
caps.setCapability("app","/src/test/resources/your.apk");
caps.setCapability("appPackage","com.app.package");
caps.setCapability("appActivity",".Launchable-Activity");
```

Comment: Hi Krishnan,
Thanks for reply, But my requirement is installing the .apk file directly from shared network path, without adding that .apk file into svn repository

Comment: When executing the above command, I'm getting the following error

Comment: Exception encountered in getDriver Method: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 750 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11 11:22:43'
System info: host: 'Aspire1631', ip: '10.8.18.39', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver